# customize web application root context in apache

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, tomcat, contextroot

I have web application abc.war and I want to deploy it on Apache Tomcat.
The problem is that, by default, the path to this application is **http://<server-name>/abc**
but I want to access it as **http://<server-name>/xyz**.

I put into WAR's META-INF folder the file context.xml that is :

`<Context path="/xyz" docBase="abc" override="true" />`

The application WAR abc.war is located under **%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps** and it is extracted to **%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\abc** folder.

Also, while deployment, the file context.xml from **abc/META-INF** is copied to **%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\Catalina\localhost** as abc.xml

It seems that this should work, but I still can't access my application through **http://<server-name>/xyz**, but only through **http://<server-name>/abc**

In addition, I still see in apache log the following line while deployment of abc.war : 

**context path = /abc**

Could anybody, please, help while this doesn't work, or tell if there is any way of deploying of web application on apache such that application could be accessed by customized path (that does not relate to war-file name) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html):

The context path of this web application, which is matched against the beginning of each request URI to select the appropriate web application for processing. All of the context paths within a particular Host must be unique. If you specify a context path of an empty string (""), you are defining the default web application for this Host, which will process all requests not assigned to other Contexts.

The value of this field must **not be set** except when **statically defining a Context in server.xml**, as it will be **inferred** from the filenames used for either the **.xml context file** or the **docBase**.